# How to publish a book chapter?

Tags: publications, research-process, books, independent-researcher

I have done some research in a topic. And now i think that i have enough understanding and material that can be used to write a chapter.

However, I don't have any idea about

- How can i get it(my chapter) published.
- How can I get the invitation to write a chapter in some ones book? what If I don't have contacts?
- What would be the procedure of getting it publish.
  In short the situation is like that I am the person with a book chapter in my hand and I don't know how to get it published.

Thanks in advance for replies.

Comment: Where did you do your research? Are you a student? Do you have a supervisor?

Comment: What domain? Why not a tutorial in a journal?

Comment: @ObscureOwl I have done research in my final year thesis of my bachelor's thesis. Now I am doing the job. Currently I don't have a supervisor. And my thesis professor is so busy that he did not even had a time to respond to my email.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Is there any other way?

Comment: @user2768 This is a good option I will consider it.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I want to build my academic profile so that i would be able to get Masters scholarships for abroad. As in Pakistan, right now our educational system is not much strong. Now as you said it is difficult for me to publish a book chapter, then what are possible steps i could take to build my academic profile apart from publishing papers in journals and conferences.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are thinking of a review volume: you'll need to tell the editor of the review volume you are able to contribute, and the editor needs to choose you to contribute. Problem is of course you might not know there's a review volume being planned for the topic (they don't usually solicit contributions publicly).

Your best chance is to either be the editor yourself or to be well-known enough that anyone putting together a review volume will invite you. If you want to do the former, you'll need to put together a publication proposal and try to convince a publisher to agree. This will not be trivial; you'll need to show you are indeed an authority in the field. In the same way, if you are an authority in the field then there's a good chance someone putting together a review volume will invite you anyway.

Either way, review volumes aren't something for which it is trivial to contribute. If you don't have any contacts, you're stuck - no reputable publisher will publish your chapter. That said, if you really want, you could self-publish or put a manuscript on the arXiv or something, but it won't carry as much impact.